# Index renaming fails with curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to rename my index with the intruction [enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)
and I run the intructions in this way:

```
    curl -XPOST '<ip>:9200/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'    
    {
       "source": {
         "index": "app_access_446"
       },
       "dest": {
         "index": "app_access_447"
       }
    }
    '
```

But I get this response

```
   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid version format: -H CONTENT-TYPE: HTTP/1.1"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid version format: -H CONTENT-TYPE: HTTP/1.1"},"status":400}curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 36
```

What I am doing wrong?

greetings niesel

Comment: Are you missing a single quote after the port number? + you need to use the `_reindex` endpoint

Comment: Oh, thank you. That was the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPOST '<ip>:9200/_reindex' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'    
{
   "source": {
     "index": "app_access_446"
   },
   "dest": {
     "index": "app_access_447"
   }
}
'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.